# Excel formula to return value in a cell to the right

Tags: excel-formula

OK hoping someone can help.

I have a formula in one cell as follows:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$R$16,MATCH(A20,$F$2:$F$16,0),MATCH(B20,$G$1:$R$1,-1))
```

This returns the cell value from a table given the values from another table.

Now I would like a formula to return the cell value that is one cell to the right of the cell that the above formula is referencing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of INDEX(array, row, col) use INDEX(array, row, col+1), i.e., add an +1 in your formula.

Comment: If the value in B20 matches R1 this formula would return #REF.

Comment: @user2809998: So is this an answer which can be accepted? @unique2: There is no B20 in my formula ;-). The problem you are pointing at can be solved by choosing `array' just one column larger, which is more elegant than hardcoding fixed references. =INDEX($G$2:$S$16,MATCH(A20,$F$2:$F$16,0),MATCH(B20,$G$1:$R$1,-1)+1)

Answer (score 0):

Just shift your array one to the right:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$S$16,MATCH(A20,$F$2:$F$16,0),MATCH(B20,$G$1:$R$1,-1))
```